# Align and center two divs and two headers

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs and 2 H4 headers which need to be in a line. Tried to align with text-align and float left but it doesn't work.

From my understanding, side by side alignment can be achieved by using float for the elements but it is not happening in my case. Also unable to center them. At present trying to use margin left with a 30% which I believe is not a proper solution. The images below shows how it looks currently and how I am trying to make it look.

**HTML**

```
<div class="k-legend-title">
<div class="k-stat-title-color-box" style="background-color: #3DA1ED;"></div>
<h4 class="">Driver 1</h4>
<div class="k-stat-title-color-box" style="background-color: #652D91;"></div>
<h4 class="">Driver 2</h4>
```

**CSS**

```
.k-legend-title{
    color: #C3CF01;
}

.k-stat-title-color-box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
```

**Current Layout**

[image]

**Trying to get this layout. Center and in 1 line**

[image]

Comment: The reason your float doesn't give the desired result, is because h4 are also block elements. So while your divs are floated, the h4's are not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make them inline-level, don't use floats. Then you can align them horizontally through `text-align` on their container, and align them vertically through `vertical-align` on themselves.

```css
.k-legend-title {
  color: #C3CF01;
  text-align: center;
}
.k-stat-title-color-box, h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
.k-stat-title-color-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="k-legend-title">
  <div class="k-stat-title-color-box" style="background-color: #3DA1ED;"></div>
  <h4>Driver 1</h4>
  <div class="k-stat-title-color-box" style="background-color: #652D91;"></div>
  <h4>Driver 2</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default h1-h6 elements has **display: block**, you should use display: inline-block in this situation.

```
h4{
  display: inline-block;
}

h4:first-of-type{
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t6j1yuqh/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:inline-block` with parent using `text-align:center`:

```
.k-legend-title {
   text-align:center; 
   color: #C3CF01;
 }

 .k-stat-title-color-box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top: 6px;
 }
 h4 {
   display:inline-block;
 }
 .k-legend-title h4:first-of-type {
     margin-right: 10px;
 }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kaarccq4/